# Signing JAR to allow its classes to have internet access

Tags: java, security, jar, jar-signing

I have a Java application that requires internet access since it embeds a web browser by means of a [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) JavaFX component.

If the application is not packaged in a Jar, it executes without problems.
However, when packaged in a Jar it cannot access internet anymore (e.g., it cannot load the remote Javascript files it requires, such as JQuery).

I tried to fix it signing the jar with:

```
jarsigner myjar myalias
```

And the command succeeds, although with the following warning:

> Warning:  The signer certificate will expire within six months. No
>   -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the
>   signer certificate's expiration date (2014-07-08) or after any future
>   revocation date.

However, the application still does not have internet access (the embedded browser still cannot load remote script files).
I am supposed to sign it in other way ? maybe including a certificate from a recognized certificate authority ?

I have also configured permissions in my `~/.java.policy` file as follows:

```
keystore "file:<userpath>/.keystore", "jks";

grant signedBy "myalias" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I am trying in OSX 10.9.2 and Java 1.8.0-b132

**UPDATE**

It turned out that the embedded browser is executed differently if the application is embedded in a Jar or not, and this goes beyond security permissions.

I do not have idea what is the reason of this, but this can lead you to all sort of wrong conclusions if you do not know it. A nasty bug probably.

For example, one of the things that I observed, is that when no packaged in a Jar, beginning the embedded web page like this worked fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
...
```

But when packaged in a Jar this gave me problems (probably the xhtml1-strict was enforced) so I had to replace it by a simple `<html>` tag.

This was not the only different behaviour, but the main thing that was giving me problems.

Comment: Define 'still does not have Internet access'. What happens instead?

Comment: The remote scripts required in the embedded browser cannot be loaded. All the html content is shown and Javascript works.

Comment: `Trusted-Library` is not for whole application (as the name suggests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information would be great, are you trying to deploy with native packaging, are you using webstart, etc..

Anyhow, based on your question, I'd suggest you take a look at letting Netbeans help you with the signing etc.

I prefer creating an FXML based application, that way the code & interface stays separate. In this case I'm just throwing in some HTML directly.

I've deployed a number of JavaFX applications using WebView with no problem. If you're deploying locally, I wouldn't worry about the certificate expiring at this point, unless you're using webstart.

Here's some sample code that works fine, it uses a WebView & accesses the internet to get jQuery.

The main class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Sam
 */
public class WebViewTestJDK8 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The controller:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;


public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String html = "<html>\n"
                        + "<head>\n"
                        + "<title>jQuery Hello World</title>\n"
                        + " \n"
                        + "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.6.min.js\"></script>\n"
                        + " \n"
                        + "</head>\n"
                        + " \n"
                        + "<body>\n"
                        + " \n"
                        + "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"
                        + " \n"
                        + "$(document).ready(function(){\n"
                        + " $(\"#msgid\").html(\"Hello World by JQuery\");\n"
                        + "});\n"
                        + " \n"
                        + "</script>\n"
                        + " \n"
                        + "Hello World by HTML\n"
                        + " \n"
                        + "<div id=\"msgid\">\n"
                        + "</div>\n"
                        + " \n"
                        + "</body>\n"
                        + "</html>";

                webView.getEngine().loadContent(html);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

The FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="pane" prefHeight="367.0" prefWidth="446.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="webviewtest.jdk8.FXMLDocumentController">
  <children>
    <WebView fx:id="webView" prefHeight="367.0" prefWidth="446.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hi @simsam7, I have edited my question. The jar is not embedded in a html but it embeds a browser as a JavaFX component. I am not using webstart and I am not sure what is the "native packaging" you mention. Your answer seems to imply that the current signature should suffice, is that correct ? Please tell me if you know how I can debug this.

Comment: @Sergio, my sample code does embed a browser as a JavaFX component - that's the "WebView". To be quite honest, I couldn't be bothered with trying to get JavaFX to compile & get signed correctly using the command line.. If that's really what you want, I'll look at it. The sample code does compile to a JAR (using Netbeans) and works fine.

Comment: I do not need to compile or sign the jar using the command line. But I do need to execute the jar from the command line, it is called from another program in fact (so the jar should be in the classpath). Could you post the jar of your example to see if it executes in my computer from the command line ? Which OS are you using btw ? I am working with OSX 10.9.2.

Comment: I use both Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows 8.. this particular JAR was compiled on Windows, but runs fine on Linux, launching from the command line. Here's a link to the JAR: http://sharesend.com/xirm07x0

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how you execute it from the terminal? I tried with "java webviewtest.jdk8.WebViewTestJDK8 classpath=WebViewTest-JDK8.jar " in the download directory but it does not work.

Comment: Sure, just by navigating to the folder and: java -jar WebViewTest-JDK8.jar

Comment: I see a "Hello World by HTML" and "Hello World by JQuery" lines, I guess that means it has internet access, right ?

Comment: Apparently you are trying with JavaFX 2.2, since I see this in your manifest: "JavaFX-Version: 2.2". I am trying with JavaFX 8, but it should not be the reason of my problems I guess. Trying to find the differences now. Will be back to you soon.

Comment: Yes, the jQuery line tells you that it has access to the internet. JavaFX 2.2 is the latest version & I'm using Java 8.

Comment: Just in case, are you signing the jar with a certificate from a  recognized certificate authority ? Just exploring all possible hypotheses ... I guess I will try to recreate and sign your jar myself to see if it still works.

Comment: Netbeans already automatically self-signs the JAR, so no, not a cert authority. Does the JAR execute for you? I'm pretty sure even without being signed it would still run, but with a warning on execute, since it's a standalone.

Comment: Hi @simsam7, updated the question with the solution to the problem. I am very happy to give you the bounty for all the help debugging it you gave me, but apparently still need to wait few hours for that. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Sergio, glad you got it figured out! Thanks for the bounty!